# How can i print the date ,when i select the date from <input type="date" > using AJAX?

Tags: html, ajax

I want to get the value of **date1** input field without submitting the submit button.

```
<input type="date" name="date1"  />
```

How can i print the value ,when i select a particular date from calendar .
Please Share AJAX code to get the value.
List all the code please.

Comment: Maybe add an event listener on change, then retrieve the value?

Comment: Can you write the code for me.

Comment: No, that is exactly what SO is **not** for... search for `addEventListener` and try it yourself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use change event handler

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[type="date"]').change(function(){
       console.log(this.value);       
    });
});
```

Comment: Not working , please clear the concept , i only want to print the value.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/94q3ds4q/ take a look, alert shows after selecting whole date from calendar

Comment: Thanks I understood